# expl3: how to get a control sequence's name

Tags: expl3

`\__cs_get_function_name:N` seems to be deprecated. How would one modify the code below to return the function's name?

```
\documentclass{l3doc}
\usepackage{expl3}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_set:Nn \__foo:n{(#1)}

\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn

\exp_last_unbraced:No \use_i:nnn {\cs_split_function:N \__foo:n} % expect __foo % returns __foo:n`


\ExplSyntaxOff

\end{document}
```

UPDATE:

log's head:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (TeX Live 2018) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2018.6.16)  17 JUN 2018 19:54
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**split_function_name.tex
(./split_function_name.tex
LaTeX2e <2018-04-01> patch level 5
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3doc.cls
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
Package: expl3 2018-06-01 L3 programming layer (loader) 

(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3-code.tex
Package: expl3 2018-06-01 L3 programming layer (code)
\c_max_int=\count80
\l_tmpa_int=\count81
\l_tmpb_int=\count82
\g_tmpa_int=\count83
```

Comment: I edited the question with the log showing "This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (TeX Live 2018) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2018.6.16)  and Package: expl3 2018-06-01 L3 programming layer (loader) " Here's a [snapshot of the pdf](https://postimg.cc/image/4tx91x7cx/)

Comment: Sorry. I misread your question. (And am out of date to boot, it seems.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a function, whose name begins with `__`, from another module is *always* deprecated: such functions are not guaranteed to be stable.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_new:Nn \erwann_get_function_name:N
 {
  \__erwann_get_function_name_a:f { \cs_split_function:N \__foo:n }
 }
\cs_new:Nn \__erwann_get_function_name_a:n
 {
  \use_i:nnn #1
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__erwann_get_function_name_a:n { f }

\tl_set:Nf \l_tmpa_tl { \erwann_get_function_name:N \__foo:n }
\tl_show:N \l_tmpa_tl

% shows 
% > \l_tmpa_tl=__foo.
```

You get the same result with

```
\exp_last_unbraced:Nf \use_i:nnn \cs_split_function:N \__foo:n
```

so, for instance,

```
\tl_set:Nf \l_tmpa_tl
 {
  \exp_last_unbraced:Nf \use_i:nnn \cs_split_function:N \__foo:n
 }
\tl_show:N \l_tmpa_tl
```

would again show

```
> \l_tmpa_tl=__foo.
```

So you could define

```
\cs_new:Nn \erwann_get_function_name:N
 {
  \exp_last_unbraced:Nf \use_i:nnn \cs_split_function:N #1
 }
```

Take your pick. In both cases, the function works with `f`-expansion.

Answer (score 2):

What makes you think that `\cs_split_function:N \__foo:n` will yield a result after expanding **o**nce (indicated by the `o` parameter)?  Use `\exp_last_unbraced:Nx` instead (e**x**haustive expansion).

Comment: You can use `f`-type (or the new `e`-type) here if in an expansion context.